# Suggested edit custom reject reason box UI issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing

The suggested edit rejection dialog looks a bit strange right now - the custom rejection reason text box is a bit too wide compared to the dialog box.

- Chrome 16:
  can't resize the custom text box horizontally, looks like there are two of them stacked

[image]

- Firefox 9: can resize in all directions, but also looks like there are two of them

[image]

(Note: doesn't happen on Stack Overflow right now with the same browsers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the next build on, resizing is disabled for text areas even in browsers that (wrongly) enable it by default, making this essentially [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (even if it's not exactly what you wanted). See [my rant on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96143/prevent-the-post-text-area-from-being-obscured-by-the-sidebar-when-resized/118644#118644) for some more details.

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't whatever magic the question/answer editor does be emulated on these other edit areas though? It handles the vertical-only resizing quite well.